# Regex match string before and after a specific character

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I would like to make a grouping to select the strings before AND after a specific character, in this case it's the Colon.

Example:

```
First: foo Last: bar
```

I would like to Match First and foo in group 1 and Last bar in group 2

Group1:    `First foo`

Group2:    `Last bar`

---

I currently have

```
([^:]*)+([^:*])
```

Which only matches everything that's not a colon, which isn't exactly what i'm looking for. What are some ways or patterns with regex where i can match before and after a certain character?

Comment: Try [`/([^:]+):\s*(.*?)(?=\w+:|$)/`](https://regex101.com/r/mi2eGe/1/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew using a non capturing group to get just the required matches might be slightly better: `(?:[^:]+):\s*(.*?)(?=\w+:|$)`

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to use `replace` if you want to group them in one group

Comment: @Tibrogargan Well, I am not really sure of the required output. It looks like Group 1 should be `First foo` and that is impossible since the texts are not continuous. See [**this JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/nf2dkdpf/2/), you may still use that regex above, but join the groups together.

Comment: You forgot to put that "certain character" in your `regex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want the colon removed, but still have the surrounding text in one group, you'll need to use some string manipulation after executing the regular expression:

```js
var s = "First: foo Last: bar",
    re = /\s*([^:]*?)\s*:\s*([^:\s]*)/g,
    result = [];
while (match = re.exec(s)) {
    result.push(match[1] + ' ' + match[2]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Note that it can be ambiguous which word belongs where, when there are more spaces, for example in `First: foo hello there: bar`.

Answer (score 0):

The texts you want to get into single group is not a streak of continuous chars, thus, it is impossible to achieve. You need to grab the two parts, key and value separately, and then join them:

```js
var rx = /([^:]+):\s*(.*?)(?=\w+:|$)/g;
var s = "First: foo Last: bar";
var m, res=[];
while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
  res.push([m[1].trim(),m[2].trim()].join(" "));
}
console.log(res);
```

See the [regex demo at regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aKFJ9u/1). Details:

- `([^:]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than `:`
- `:` - a `:`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\w+:|$)` - followed with 1+ word chars and `:` or end of string.

Comment: just out of curiousity why are you using the `?` sign in `(.*?)` ? why not just go with `(.*)` , just wanted to know. Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aKFJ9u/2) and compare with the [one in the answer](https://regex101.com/r/sY5fI5/1). `.*?` will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as **few** as possible and `.*` will match any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as **many** as possible. Note that my regex will return `[ "First foo hello",  "there bar"]` for the `First: foo hello there: bar` input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
([a-zA-Z]+:\s*[a-zA-Z]+)
```

You can try it out on the link **[HERE](https://regex101.com/r/QXPC3x/2/)**.

```
'First: foo Last: bar'.match(/([a-zA-Z]+:\s*[a-zA-Z]+)/g) // ["First: foo", "Last: bar"]
```